# How to read a checkbox value generated from a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi, I'm facing this problem getting the value of the checkbox value that I generated from C# code in a label. The output is just as I wanted, but i've tried using the below codes, but the object tells me its value is null. Someone please guide me, I need help.

```
HtmlInputCheckBox MyCheckBox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
            MyCheckBox = (HtmlInputCheckBox)this.FindControl("Qn" + temp);
            bool isChacked = MyCheckBox.Checked;
```

### MyMethod

```
string table1 = "";

ArrayList listofquestionnonradio = DBManager.GetSurveyQuestionNonRadio();
ArrayList listofallquestion = DBManager.GetAllSurveyQuestions();
int lastcount = Convert.ToInt32(listofquestionnonradio.Count);

table1 = "<br/><table>";

foreach (SurveyQuestions surv in listofallquestion)
{
    if (surv.Questionid <= listofquestionnonradio.Count)
    {
        //get questions without radio
        table1 += "<tr><td><b>Q" + temp + ")</b></td><td>" + surv.Question + "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>Ans:</td><td>";

        foreach (string subjname in listofselectsubjectnames)
        {
            //get name from excludelist
            bool result= DBManager.GetExcludedQuestionsByQidAndSubject(surv.Questionid, subjname);

            if (result == false)
            {
                string subvalue = subjname + "_val";
                table1 += "<input type=checkbox name=Qn" + counterqn + " value=" + subvalue + " >" + subjname + "<br>";
                counterqn++;
            }
        }
        table1 += "<input type=checkbox name=lastqn value=NIL)>All of the above<br/></td></tr>";
        table1 += "<tr style=height:10px></tr>";
        temp++;
    }
    else
    {
        //get questions id if they are disable
        bool result= DBManager.GetExcludedQuestionsByQid(surv.Questionid);

        if (result == false)
        {
            //get questions with radio
            table1 += "<tr><td><b>Q" + temp + ")<b></td><td>" + surv.Question + "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>Ans:</td><td>";

            table1 += "<input type=radio name=Qn" + counterqn + " value=1>Strongly disagree<br><input type=radio name=Qn" + counterqn + " value=2>Disagree<br><input type=radio name=Qn" + counterqn + " value=3>Agree<br><input type=radio name=Qn" + counterqn + " value=4>Strongly agree<br><input type=radio name=Qn" + counterqn + " value=5>Not applicable<br></td></tr>";

            table1 += "<tr style=height:10px></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            temp--;
        }
        temp++;
    }
}
table1 += "</table><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you cannot access the checkbox controls is because you are not actually using server controls, you are building up your markup yourself. Your WebForm therefore does not have any controls to find.

If you are using ASP.NET WebForms (which is what I'm assuming) then why don't you use the server controls to build your table rather than manually building the HTML? You would then be able to view/modify them in your code-behind.

Take a look at the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control for a start to see how you could build up a table/grid-view easier than what you are currently doing.